# How to get Mouse input inside a C console program on Windows-10?

Tags: c, windows, cmd, windows-10, windows-console

I need to interact with user's mouse input in my simple C console program. I did some research and found [a related Microsoft's docs on their page here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/reading-input-buffer-events). For a start, I copied all of their sample-code and pasted that into my editor. Upon compilation, it gets compiled well, with a nice little '.exe' which when run, tells/prints correctly all 'Key events' and 'resize events', But No Mouse event! How to successfully get mouse input inside C console program? My [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is the given [sample-code here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/reading-input-buffer-events) on Microsoft site, as i used that sample-code verbatim! I'm using Windows 10 Pro (1703), just in case.

---

**EDIT:** - It appears to be a problem which is not unique to me. Another StackOverflow user [also reported the same problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42213161/console-mouse-input-not-working) on his Windows-10 system. [His provided MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42213161/console-mouse-input-not-working) was also working on Windows-7, but not on Windows-10, just like my quoted-MCVE on Microsoft's site as a sample-code might be working on older Windows-versions, but not on windows-10, where *'Quick Edit Mode'* seemingly is enabled in *'Console-Defaults'*.

Comment: Are you running this in your IDE?

Comment: I have compiled and run the same code example using Windows 7 and MSVC 2015, it prints out mouse events as intended, when run from console or from GUI file viewer. I am not using the IDE.

Comment: @stark No. I run that compiled '.exe' independently, outside IDE. Typed(pasted) code in 'atom'. and compiled source at command-prompt via GCC using command 'gcc inputwin.c -o mouse' (inputwin.c is filename in which i pasted that sample and this command generated '.exe' named mouse). I then run that mouse.exe from windows explorer from that folder where it was residing.

Comment: @WeatherVane I am using Windows 10 Pro (1703). And my compiler is GCC. Compiled that sample at command-prompt.

Comment: @WeatherVane After reading your comment, I went on to install Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 Version 15.3.3 (Installed Version: Community) containing Micosoft Visual C++ 2017, and created 'New Project (Windows Console Application)'. Pasted all that sample code verbatim! Ran 'Build Solution' which generated '.exe' with default project name ('ConsoleApplication1.exe) in its default path 'C:\Users\FAQi\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe'. Went there. Ran that. Same result! "...tells/prints correctly all 'Key events' and 'resize events', But No Mouse event!"

Comment: I am sorry you went to such trouble with still no result.

Comment: @WeatherVane Oh. I was just documenting my attempt for other potential visitors who might have suspected fault in my way of compiling. I indeed thank you for making me find fault elsewhere, other than in that sample-code, which i have found and have posted the solution below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After spending hours i have found the culprit for failure of that quoted-in-my-question Microsoft's official [sample code here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/reading-input-buffer-events). And the culprit is the very console itself! Actually it's a *'setting'* namely **'Quick Edit Mode'** for the *'Console Windows'* .

You can access it by:

1. Opening command-prompt and right-clicking on its title-bar and then clicking 'Defaults'
2. A Dialog box would appear, titled *'Console Windows Properties'*. There in *Options* tab, under *Edit Options* sub-heading, you would find **'Quick Edit Mode'** checkbox!

I have attached screen-captures below:

[image: Appeared Menu after doing Right-Click on Command-Prompt's title bar][image: Console Windows Properties]

The problem was being caused by that **'Quick Edit Mode'** option which was enabled(checkbox is checked) by default on my Windows 10. And in this enabled status, this **'Quick Edit Mode'** was consuming all the Mouse-Events and wasn't dispatching any to my '.exe' .

When this **'Quick Edit Mode'** options' checkbox is unchecked (disabled), then program runs fine as intended/coded in that [sample-code here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/reading-input-buffer-events), telling/printing all Mouse events. [ Phew! ]

**NOTE:** The change in 'Console Properties' *requires relaunch* of the console, to take effect.

---

**EDIT: IMPROVED 'PORTABLE' SOLUTION!**

The solution above is not 'portable'. That's just for the local-machine and of course, it's also 'manual work'. To make that [sample-code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/reading-input-buffer-events) work without requiring user to *disable* **Quick Edit Mode** *'manually'* as explained above, we can *disable* **Quick Edit Mode** programmatically by adding following lines of code inside that [sample-code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/reading-input-buffer-events)

```
        /* 
           Step-1:
           Disable 'Quick Edit Mode' option programmatically
        */
        fdwMode = ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS;
        if (! SetConsoleMode(hStdin, fdwMode) )
             ErrorExit("SetConsoleMode");
        /* 
           Step-2:
           Enable the window and mouse input events,
           after you have already applied that 'ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS'
           to disable 'Quick Edit Mode'
        */
        fdwMode = ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT | ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT;
        if (! SetConsoleMode(hStdin, fdwMode) )
            ErrorExit("SetConsoleMode");
```

I found about that '`ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS`' option on [Microsoft's docs about `SetConsoleMode()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode)

After we have applied `ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS` in `SetConsoleMode()` function, our program would receive/print all 'Mouse Events' even though the user has 'Quick Edit Mode' option enabled in *Console Defaults* options. And after our program has finished doing its job (receiving Mouse events in this super simple scenario) user's *Console Defaults* would be undisturbed because before our program quits, it would restore user's original (saved in the start of our program) *Console Mode* as follows:

```
         /* Restore original console mode before exit. */
         SetConsoleMode(hStdin, fdwSaveOldMode);
```

As done in that [sample-code there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/reading-input-buffer-events), which works well, but *fails* to print Mouse events if user has 'Quick Edit Mode' enabled in his console. Therefore, to make that [sample-code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/reading-input-buffer-events) work in scenarios where user's *Console Defaults* has 'Quick Edit Mode' enabled, we should include/put inside that [sample-code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/reading-input-buffer-events) the code-snippet (of applying `ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS`) as shown in this **'EDIT'** section above.

Comment: Works well but I found that the snippet to disable quick mode needs to be placed after GetStdHandle in the sample code, if I place the snippet before GetStdHandle the program exits with the GetConsoleMode error.